# Creating multiple modal windows with same styling but different content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have 140 link items that essentially are going to do a modal window of a user profile for each link. I have created a div(the modal window) and styled it but the problem is that the elements on each user profile have to be different. So there is a div containing 3 images which are going to be different for everyone, a profile picture, a paragraph of text and social icons.

What would be the easiest way to make this work? Been looking for some information for couple of hours with no results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a single blank modal (yes, one will do).
2. Everytime you display content to it, *clear the body of the modal first*
3. Load the content you want to display
4. Show the modal.

Do steps 2 to 4 everytime you want to show it with different content.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Thats what I was thinking of doing but what I'm having trouble figuring out is how do I make the modal to show the content that is meant to be showed when the link is going to be pressed?